# AWS Terraform child module with specific resources in different region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-acm

All of my Terraform infrastructure is currently in `us-east-2`. Below is from my root module.

```
# Default
provider "aws" {
  region                   = "us-east-2"
  shared_credentials_files = ["~/.aws/credentials"]

  default_tags {
    tags = {
      ManagedBy = "Terraform"
    }
  }
}

# Needed because CloudFront can only use ACM certs generated in us-east-1
provider "aws" {
  alias                    = "us-east-1"
  region                   = "us-east-1"
  shared_credentials_files = ["~/.aws/credentials"]

  default_tags {
    tags = {
      ManagedBy = "Terraform"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm writing a Terraform module to create a static site in AWS (S3, CloudFront, ACM, Route53, etc...).

The module creates all of these resources, but [CloudFront requires ACM certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html#https-requirements-aws-region) to be in `us-east-1`.

> To use a certificate in AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) to require HTTPS between viewers and CloudFront, make sure you request (or import) the certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) Region (us-east-1).

In the child module (currently hosted on GitHub), I saw that I can set a `provider` to use a different provider.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "site" {
  # Needed because CloudFront can only use ACM certs generated in us-east-1
  provider          = aws.us-east-1
  domain_name       = aws_route53_zone.site.name
  validation_method = "DNS"
  subject_alternative_names = [
    "*.${aws_route53_zone.site.name}"
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

When I call the module, I set a `providers` block...

```
module "static_site_mydomain_com" {
  source = "github.com/myname/terraform-aws-static-site"

  providers = {
    aws.us-east-1 = aws.us-east-1
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

However, that results in this warning.

```
╷
│ Warning: Reference to undefined provider
│ 
│   on site_mydomain_com.tf line 5, in module "static_site_mydomain_com":
│    5:     aws.us-east-1 = aws.us-east-1
│ 
│ There is no explicit declaration for local provider name "aws.us-east-1" in module.static_site_mydomain_com, so
│ Terraform is assuming you mean to pass a configuration for "hashicorp/aws".
│ 
│ If you also control the child module, add a required_providers entry named "aws.us-east-1" with the source address
│ "hashicorp/aws".
│ 
│ (and 3 more similar warnings elsewhere)
```

Where is this provider supposed to go? In the root module, or the child module? I've [read](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers) that child modules shouldn't contain provider blocks. To be clear, everything the module creates should be in `us-east-2`, except the `aws_acm_certificate`, which should be in us-east-1`.

Comment: @CollinD, sorry, I removed the ChatGPT reference

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#provider-aliases-within-modules. However if your child module is just using standard resources then I would suggest just passing the provider as `providers ={aws = aws.us-east-1}` the means in the child module when ever it's using the aws provider it will be with the US-east-1 config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this. This creates everything in `us-east-2`, except the specific resources I wanted in `us-east-1`.

```
# Default
provider "aws" {
  region                   = "us-east-2"
  shared_credentials_files = ["~/.aws/credentials"]
}

# Needed because CloudFront can only use ACM certs generated in us-east-1
provider "aws" {
  alias                    = "us-east-1"
  region                   = "us-east-1"
  shared_credentials_files = ["~/.aws/credentials"]
}

module "static_site_domain_com" {
  source = "github.com/myname/mymodule"

  providers = {
    aws.us-east-1 = aws.us-east-1
  }
...
...
```

In the module itself, I have this set.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.2"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source                = "hashicorp/aws"
      version               = "~> 5.15.0"
      configuration_aliases = [aws.us-east-1]
    }
  }
}
```